# TestRunner in Cucumber does not run my feature files

Tags: gradle, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I have been trying to run my feature files using TestRunner but it has failed to do so.
When I right click on TestRunner -> Run As JUnit, nothing happens and it just shows Finished.
Console tab has no messages and JUnit tab has no test runs. It just shows "finished after X seconds".

[I attached my package structure for you to check.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIPEI.png)

I am using Gradle and Eclipse IDE

Here are is my TestRunner Class:

```
package runners;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import io.cucumber.junit.*;
    
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/java/feature",
        glue = {"stepDefinition"},
        tags = "@Login",
    )

public class TestRunner {
    
}
```

here is my code for step definition:

```
package stepDefinition;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import cucumber.TestContext;
import io.cucumber.java.en.*;
import managers.FileReaderManager;
import dataProvider.ConfigFileReader;

public class CommonStep {
    
    private WebDriver driver;
    private TestContext testContext;
    
    public CommonStep (ConfigFileReader configFile, TestContext testContext) {
        
        this.testContext = testContext;
        this.driver = testContext.getWebDriverManager().getDriver();
    }
    
    @Given("the user navigates to Login Page {string}")
    public void TheUserIsInLoginPage(String url) throws Throwable {
        
        driver.get(FileReaderManager.getInstance().getConfigReader().getApplicationUrl());
        testContext.getPageObjectManager().getBasePage().waitForPageToLoad(30);;
        
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

Am I missing something?
Thank you for your help!

I tried putting my feature files under src/test/resources folder and changed my TestRunner features = "src/test/resources/feature" and still no luck. I am getting the same output as the original issue.

Comment: BTW, I also put a @Login Tags on my Feature files:

'@Login  
Scenario:User Successfully logs in Page
GIVEN the user navigates...
WHEN the user enters...
THEN the user is "successfully" Logged In

Comment: Everything is running perfectly fine if I right click on my .feature file -> Run As -> Cucumber Feature. But when running TestRunner -> Run As JUnit, it does not work.

Comment: Start with https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton and maybe read https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html#

Comment: What JUnit version are you using and is your configuration correct?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is the JUnit version your Test Runner class is using. Try executing your `TestRunner.java` with JUnit 4. To do this, open the Run Configurations context menu for your test runner class, and select JUnit 4 from the drop down.

[image]

The fact you are using `@CucumberOptions` tells me you are using a JUnit 4 Cucumber configuration. This is why when you try to run your test as a JUnit test it fails, but when you run it as a Cucumber Feature it works fine. Basically, you are taking JUnit out of the picture.

If you have JUnit 5 (Jupiter) installed, it tends to default to this version to run your tests. Cucumber with JUnit 4 and 5 configurations are not really compatible. If you want to use JUnit 5, I suggest you configure your project following these [instructions](https://qaautomation.expert/2022/08/29/integration-of-cucumber7-with-junit5/). I must clarify that the linked example runs tests as Maven tests and not as JUnit test, but does use the JUnit 5 platform.

**EDIT**:

Just to give you a quick rundown on how to convert your project to Cucumber using JUnit 5.

Your runner, step definitions, and feature files must under a common package. For my sample project, I created the `com.example` package. Therefore, your structure should be something like this:

```
src/test/java
  |
  - com/example/runner/TestRunner.java
  - com/example/definitions/StepDefinitions.java

src/test/resources
  |
  - com/example/features/MyTests.feature
```

Your `TestRunner` class should be annotated as follows:

```
import static io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Constants.GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME;

import org.junit.platform.suite.api.ConfigurationParameter;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectClasspathResource;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite;

@Suite
@SelectClasspathResource("com/example")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "com.example")
public class Runner {}
```

And, as a minimum, your POM should contain the following

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>SeleniumWithCucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>SeleniumWithCucumber</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SeleniumWithCucumber</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <cucumber.version>7.10.1</cucumber.version>
        <selenium.version>4.4.0</selenium.version>
        <webdrivermanager.version>5.2.1</webdrivermanager.version>
        <junit.jupiter.version>5.9.1</junit.jupiter.version>
        <apache.common.version>2.4</apache.common.version>
        <projectlombok.version>1.18.24</projectlombok.version>
        <maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.10.1</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
        <maven.surefire.plugin.version>3.0.0-M7</maven.surefire.plugin.version>
        <maven.compiler.source.version>17</maven.compiler.source.version>
        <maven.compiler.target.version>17</maven.compiler.target.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JUnit Platform -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Selenium -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Web Driver Manager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>${webdrivermanager.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Apache Common -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.commons.io</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.common.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${projectlombok.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source.version}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.surefire.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <properties>
                        <configurationParameters>
                cucumber.junit-platform.naming-strategy=long
            </configurationParameters>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Lastly, make sure your test runner class uses JUnit 5 instead of JUnit 4. I already provided instructions on how to change this parameter in your run configurations context menu.

**In short, you have two options**:

1. Change your current project configuration to run with JUnit 4, or
2. Change your project as I indicated in this last edit so it can run with JUnit 5.

Comment: If you need (or want) to run as a Maven test, let me know and I will edit this answer.